# Assiging the maximum value of a column to the row

Tags: matlab, max

Say we have the following matrix

```
1 3 6
5 4 7
5 3 9
```

What I'm trying to do is for each row, I assign it the `maximum` value of the column. So, for instance, I'm expecting the following output:

```
x(1) = 6
x(2) = 7
x(3) = 9
```

I tried doing that using by writing the code below, but didn't get the expected putput:

```
x=[1 3 6;5 4 7; 5 3 9]
[rows, columns] = size(x);
for i=1:columns
    for j=1:rows
        [maximum, position] = max(x(j,:));
        disp('MAXIMUM')
        x(j)=maximum
    end
end
```

What should I do to get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, you can just use the `max` function. It naturally operates on columns, therfore, some transposition is necessary.

```
x=[1 3 6;5 4 7; 5 3 9]

y = max(x')'

y =

   6
   7
   9
```

You can even reassing the values *on the fly*

```
x = max(x')'.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I assign each maximum value for the relevant row as shown in my question?

Comment: In principle `x` is a matrix, whilst the `maximum` is an array. If you want to write on `x`, you should write in a matrix fashion (2 indices, i.e. *2d-like entrances*).

if you do `y = max(x')'`, then `y(1) = 6` , `y(2)=7` ... as you like

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in `max` function with a dimension specifier: `max(x,[],dim)`.

In your case, assuming your matrix is called `A`:

```
>> x=max(A,[],2)
ans =

     6
     7
     9
```